# Safari browser inactive after 2 hours

Tags: macos, safari

I've been trying to resolve this issue with my MacBook for 2 months and finally reaching out for help.
When I Power Cycle my MacBook Pro (2017, Catalina 10.15.7), I can use Safari successfully for a while. After about 2 hours of non use, I try to use Safari and it will not reload or bring up new websites. Same with Chrome. However, I can use Firefox successfully after 2 hours.

- I have made sure browsers are up to date with latest version.
  I cannot move to Big Sur since a couple of pieces of software I need for mainframe interface are not going to do anymore updates. We are investigating options at this point for other solutions.
- I have turned off Safari extensions to make sure these are not the
  issues.
- I have RoboForms, DropBox and CleanMyMac running in the
  background. Turning these 3 off did not have any impact on the issue.
- I turned off screensaver to eliminate it as a possible culprit.
- I have tried turning off WiFi and changing to a different network but
  the browser still does not work. (I use my iPhone on cellular data and not connected to network.) I have combed through my network settings to make sure Proxy is not turned on by accident and DNS is using the router.
- I have used Activity Monitor to stop all agents that seem to be associated with Safari and Chrome but that did not resolve the issue.

  - Safari shows the blue "attempting to connect" progress bar in the URL window at 1/8th progress but never completes or shows an error message.
  - Chrome starts loading the website but fails and shows "unable to reach server" message.
- I have cleared PRAMS on MacBook and cleared cache on the browser.
- I have tried Private Browser window on Safari and Chrome but no luck.

The only way I can get Safari to work after it gets into this state is to power cycle my MacBook. Reboot does not resolve the issue.
It's weird since I Safari and Chrome do not work but Firefox does. And I have confirmed it is new data and not cached data in Firefox.
What am I missing? Power Cycle seems to indicate some sort of memory issue but I don't believe this is the issue since I can still use Firefox browser and internet programs such as Reddit app,
Apple News, FB messenger.
I'm good with terminal windows and linux commands if there is some sort of command I can issue to turn on logging at the system level. I've looked through the logs that are turned on but I have not seen anything to relating to timeouts to resolve this. I'm just not too sure what I need to tweak to capture and resolve this issue. Wireshark shows that the commands to websites are going out and coming back since the browser tab changes to the website URL but the UI page does not display the results.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Donald

Comment: Wireshark shows the page contents are retrieved, but not rendered, even though chrome says unable to reach server? What happens if you open an html file that is on disk, will it render that?  Try a local server: open terminal, run ‘python3 -m http.server’ and open http://localhost:8000/ Have you tried creating a new user to be sure it isn’t an account setting?